# CreateView and related model fields with fixed inital values

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm working with a CreateView where I know what some of the field values will be ahead of time. In the example below, I know that the author field for a new Entry object will be the current user and I use get_initial() to preset this.

Now I would like to omit this field from my template form. I've tried several approaches:

- Simply commenting out the author field in the form template leads to an invalid form.
- Leaving 'author' out of fields. Nope.

And here's a related problem. The example below involves a relationship to a User object that exists. But what if I need to *create* an object, say an auth Group for editors? I've tried creating a placeholder group and renaming it ... and, well, that didn't work very well.

```
#
# model
#
class Author(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 60)
    user = OneToOneField(to = User, related_name = 'author_user', on_delete = CASCADE)

class Entry(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length = 60)
    author = ForeignKey(to = Author, related_name = 'entry_author')

#
# view
#
class EntryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ('title', 'author')

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(EntryCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial['author'] = get_object_or_404(Author, user = self.request.user)
        return initial

#
# template
#
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
  <label for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}">Title:</label>
  {{ form.title }}
  <label for="{{ form.author.id_for_label }}">Author:</label>
  {{ form.author }}
  <p>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" value="Save" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually set user in `form_valid()` method of `EntryCreateView` class:

```
class EntryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ('title',)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        form.instance.user = user
        return super(EntryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helped and it makes the template much cleaner as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a ModelForm for the customizations you need (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/).

You can't remove author because it's required on your model currently.

Try something like this:

## In forms.py...

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['title', 'author']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        self.author = initial.get('author')
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can make modifications to the fields (set to not required, delete a field from the form fields, etc) in `__init__` or on the class.

Just import and reference this form in your views to use it.